# Check if username exists in one database

Tags: php, mysql, record, exists

```
<?
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","easyuser1","pass") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("easyuser1");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE IDnumber = '".$_POST["id_number"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","easyuser2","pass2","easyuser2");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
$id_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id_number']);
$times = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['times']);
$branch = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['branch']);
$branch_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['branch_address']);

$sql="INSERT INTO vtb (name, last_name, id_number, times, branch, branch_address)
VALUES ('$name', '$last_name', '$id_number', '$times', '$branch', '$branch_address')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=success.php">';
echo "Your information has been recorded...";

}
else
{
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=exists.php">';
echo "ID Number you entered is not in our database!";
}
?>
```

I have table `easyuser1` where I have my clients information. I have one form which my existing user (from `easyuser1`) should fill, but script should check:

1. While filling form script should check `IDnumber` of user which is recorded in `easyuser1` table. If such ID number does not exist script should echo "ID Number you entered is not in our database!". At this moment it works well.
2. After filling form information should be stored in `easyuser2` table. If user will try again filling this form script should check if `idnumber` exists in table `easyuser2`. If id number exists it should echo: "You have already filled form". So here is my problem. Thanks.

Comment: dont use that code in production server ... its vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: you are mixing tow different api .. mysql_* and mysqli_*